# Flutter Widget State Constructor Not Running

Tags: dart, flutter

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../services.dart';
import 'PersonCard.dart';

class PersonList extends StatefulWidget {  
  PersonList() {
    Services.fetchPeople();
  }

  @override
  _PersonListState createState() => new _PersonListState();
}

class _PersonListState extends State<PersonList> {    
  _PersonListState() {
    print('Helo!?'); // Not running
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          // new PersonCard('Bob', 'Wazowski', '2 minutes ago'),
          // new PersonCard('Tim', 'Alan', '5 hours ago'),
          // new PersonCard('Josh', 'Applebee', 'Yesterday'),
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Basically when my widget loads the `PersonList()` function runs that calls a web service with `Services.fetchPeople()`. Basically what I want to do is that `fetchPeople()` will return a `Map` which I can then iterate over and create `PersonCard` objects.

But the `_PersonListState()` constructor doesn't run. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Where or how do you use `PersonList`? When `Services.fetchPeople()` returns, should it not return a value? You'd need to assign this value somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `widget.people.map((p) => new PersonCard(...))` to convert data to wigets:

```
class PersonList extends StatefulWidget {  
  PersonList() {
    Services.fetchPeople().then((p) => setState(() => people = p));
  }

  List<Person> people;

  @override
  _PersonListState createState() => new _PersonListState();
}

class _PersonListState extends State<PersonList> {    
  _PersonListState() {
    print('Helo!?'); // Not running
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new ListView(
        children: widget.people.map(
            (p) => new PersonCard(p.firstName, p.lastName, p.updateTime /* or whatever that is */,
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: "The argument type 'Iterable<Map>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>" when I try to map over widget.people and pass to the 'children' prop

Comment: I think I missed a `)` (a bit difficult to see without a proper IDE). `Iterable` sounds like you omitted `toList()`. Not sure about the `<Map>` though. Can you update your question and add the concrete code you're using?

Comment: But why is the constructor not running? Is it correct?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer that. See comment below the original question.